# More complex shapes/beams of light

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

Hello fellow Blender users.

Recently I work for a client that manufactures lights and I am making a video showcase of those lights. Today he asked me if it is possible to make a video sequence where the lighting source (1 rectangle light) will change its diffusor (there are 6 in total) and it will light up an empty room with only 1 table and 1 chair. It needs to make beams of lights that follow this specific information:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I may be using Blender for a long time but I am no specialist, do you know if there is a good way to make lights like this? Should I use 2 lights in 1 place,(1 weaker and 1 stronger) or is there any specific way to make lights this way? Also, it needs to be done in Eevee not in Cycles due to how long this video is.

Also the one problem is that I cannot use Cone light sources due to rectangular shape of the lighting source that basically looks like this:

[image]

Lighting sources are those tiny little cubes and the big white rectangle at the bottom is the diffuser that will change into 6 different types of materials

Comment: Hello :). You might want to look into IES light textures [like here](https://leomoon.com/store/shaders/ies-lights-pack/). There's a dedicated IES Light node.

Comment: Hmm but the IES node works only with Cycles so this is not the right way unfortunately

Comment: Few years on TODO list https://developer.blender.org/T68472 ... But in your case I'm not sure about the goal since you run point light through rectangle diffuser in a middle of a room I don't think you can get any light beams to be visualized.